# How do I create node groups in puppet

Tags: puppet

I am in the process of setting up Puppet in our QA environment. I have created a few manifests and setup classes which are running fine. I am aware of Node definitions and have successfully created  manifests to apply on a few nodes using node definition. But I am yet to figure out how to put a group of nodes into a group so that I can use the groupname instead of having to specify each nodes in the node definition. [This](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/pe/latest/console_classes_groups.html#special-groups) URL to the puppetlabs document seem to talk only about group creation in Puppet Enterprise version. How do I create groups in community version?

This is my current nodes.pp file.

```
[root@puppet modules]# cat /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes.pp
node "saturn.qa1.example.com", "mercury.qa1.example.com" {
      include qa1check
}
```

Comment: You might need to take a look at the roles/profiles patterns (see google).  Or perhaps you can achieve what you want via hiera.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Either you use [regexes](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_node_definitions.html#regular-expression-names) for the node name, or roll your own [External Node Classifier (ENC)](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/external_nodes.html) that lets you this in a simplified fashion.

Comment: Thanks @Roman. Can we create groups if it is an Enterprise version?